# How to find pgAdminIII GUI in Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, windows-8

I got a machine where the OS is Ubuntu and already PostgreSQL has been installed. And also the credentials being provided

```
User Name: somename
Password: somepassword
```

Basically I work in Windows 8 environment and after installation of  PostgreSQL, we can find it from Start charms as

[image]

How to do the same from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Ubuntu, you can install PgAdmin3 using following console command:

```
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```

After you've done that, you can start it from the console as `pgadmin3` or you can find it in Unity by pressing `Windows` key and typing `pgadmin`.

If your Ubuntu is older than 12.04, standard provided PgAdmin may be too old to be usable and you may have to install pgadmin3 from alternative Ubuntu repository. For example, when I need to install it on Ubuntu 10.10, I do this:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rhonda/pgadmin3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```